# how to make inner join with where condition

Tags: mysql

I have tables like below,

```
CREATE TABLE `CreateEvent_tbl` (
  `Event_Id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `District` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `School` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Event_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_By` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Date_Time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Event_Id`)



CREATE TABLE `StudentDetails_tbl` (
  `Student_Id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Event_Id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Student_Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parents_Name` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Std_Ph_No` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ph_No_1` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ph_No_2` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email_Id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_By` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Date_Time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Student_Id`)



 CREATE TABLE `BuyerDetails_tbl` (
  `Event_Id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Student_Id` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Call_Buy_Id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Buyer_Id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Purchased_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `No_Of_Reference` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_By` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Date_Time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Buyer_Id`)
```

My query is :

```
      select CreateEvent_tbl.Event_Id,CreateEvent_tbl.State,StudentDetails_tbl.Student_Id,StudentDetails_tbl.Student_Name,BuyerDetails_tbl.Purchased_Date
 from CreateEvent_tbl
     inner join  BuyerDetails_tbl on CreateEvent_tbl.Event_Id=BuyerDetails_tbl.Event_Id
     inner join StudentDetails_tbl  on StudentDetails_tbl.Student_Id=BuyerDetails_tbl.Student_Id
     where BuyerDetails_tbl.Buyer_Id="B045";
```

when i search by Buyer_Id from BuyerDetails_tbl, display StudentDetails and EventDetails from StudentDetails_tbl and CreateEvent_tbl where Student_Id and Event_Id in BuyerDetails_tbl.

But above query not working,shows nothing.

where i am wrong?

Note : i am new for joining queries.

Comment: That's not the actual select tried - there are extra `'s in it resulting in invalid syntax! (Make sure to post the *actual* code verbatim.) In any case, maybe there is just no matching data? What happens if the WHERE is removed, are there results? If yes, why? (And it has nothing to do with the JOIN.) If not remove one of the JOINS, are there results as expected? Repeat this process (ie. "troubleshoot your own problem") until the actual cause is determined. If the cause is isolated, *then* ask a question - providing more context.

Comment: @user2864740 displaying correct result,if i remove where. but i want to filter result by using Buyer_Id, so what i do?

Comment: Then there is likely no buyer with an ID of `"B045"`. Make sure that such a row exists in the output without the WHERE. Might it be `"BO45"` instead? Alternatively it might be an issue with CHAR padding or spaces. To see if this is the case (and fix it if it is), try: `where TRIM(BuyerDetails_tbl.Buyer_Id) = "B045"`.

Comment: @user2864740 sorry, i got the right error now that shows like "Unknown column 'B045' in 'where clause'". what to do now?

Comment: Use the *correct* (for MySQL) quotes, as shown - although `'B045'` would also work and is correct (per the SQL Standard). That error results from not using any quotes (*wrong*: `where .. = B045`) or using the `\`` identifier quotes (*wrong*: `where .. = \`B045\``).

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you so much. i did small mistake BuyerDetails_tbl.Buyer_Id="B045" instead of BuyerDetails_tbl.Buyer_Id=' "B045" '.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a specific buyer, I would start with THAT table as the first in the list, then join to the other two.  Also, to shorten readability of the query, notice the "aliasing" of the table names (via "ce", "sd" and "bd" ) vs the long table names for all the column names and joins.

```
select 
      ce.Event_Id,
      ce.State,
      sd.Student_Id,
      sd.Student_Name,
      bd.Purchased_Date
   from 
      BuyerDetails_tbl bd
         inner join CreateEvent_tbl ce
            on bd.Event_Id = ce.Event_Id
         inner join StudentDetails_tbl sd 
            on bd.Student_Id = sd.Student_Id
   where 
      bd.Buyer_Id = "B045";
```

I would ensure you have proper indexes based on the query criteria and join conditions..

BuyerDetails_tbl -- index on (buyer_id) to optimize your WHERE criteria.